# Exporting map canvas to PNG file using custom plugin created by Plugin Builder

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm making a complement for QGIS3, how can I export the map I'm seeing in the window to .PNG using **Plugin Builder**. Without having to go through Print Composers.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you know how to create a plugin by Plugin Builder 3. If so, briefly, delete the code lines under `def run(self):` line in main file of your plugin and just add the following code under `def run(self):` line.

`self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage("your_path/file_name.png")`

If you don't know how to create a plugin by Plugin Builder 3, firstly please refer to [Qgis Plugin Builder](http://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/) page.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming QGIS 3.x.

Project> Import/Export> Export Map to Image...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this I need to integrate into a plugin that I am creating

Comment: your question asks to export map to image, and this is the answer.

Comment: I need to do this using Plugin Builder, not manually.