# QGIS Export Map as Image with fixed DPI resolution

Tags: qgis, export, resolution

I use the following option:

[Exporting map canvas to PNG file using custom plugin created by Plugin Builder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291545/exporting-map-canvas-to-png-file-using-custom-plugin-created-by-plugin-builder)

in order to get my Map canvas from QGIS straight to PNG format.

The problem is, that default images aren't as big as I would like to have.

I found some similar issue here:

[How to export the map in very high resolution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153403/how-to-export-the-map-in-very-high-resolution)

although I know how to change the resolution of my image.

The problem is, that it goes back to the default every time when I use this option.

[image]

Is there an option to make my value of DPI fixed?
I tried to check it in Settings, but I couldn't find stuff, that would match it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice solution of it, widely described here:

https://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/setting-default-resolution-when-saving-map-as-image-in-qgis/

When we want to have the default resolution other than 120 dpi, changes to the Magnifier in the Status Bar are required.

[image]